# How can i configure different X and Y sensitivity for my mouse in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, mouse

I have a  Logitech M505 Mouse which seems to be way more sensitive in the vertical plane than in the horizontal. Is there anyway I can configure sensitivity individually for the X- and Y-plane? Either directly in Windows 8 settings or through some 3rd party driver or software.

Comment: Have you installed the Logitech SetPoint software?  The description seems to indicate you might be able to adjust the sensitivity.

Comment: You can't change them individually.
Unless you're trying to change it for some specific game (which is possible in some cases)

Comment: @ramhound I just installed it, but it doesn't have this.